# How to print to network printer on click in asp.net VB 2013

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Can someone help me with how to print a textbox to a local or network printer. I am using a asp.net page with vb 2013

I have tried a couple code but nothing seem to work
Dim printDoc as Print Document = New PrintDocument
PrintDoc.Print()

Comment: If you're trying to print to a local printer from a web page the best you can do is use javascript, `window.print()`, unless you install ActiveX or some other client code.

Comment: I am using asp.net so the window.print does not work